# Regular expressions matching priority weirdness

Tags: php, regex

While writing a inflection script in php I came across a strange(at least to me) behavior. It seems that my regular expression that contains many different patterns for word endings matches the second acceptable option even when the first one is perfectly ok.

The full expression goes like this(you really don't need to pay attention to this):

```
([kpt])\1([aou])$|(?:(n)t)?([auo])$|([aeou][^aeiouyäö]+[aeiou])$|([auo][^aeiouyäö]+)$|([^aeiouyäö])(?!\6)([^aeiouyäö])(e)$|((?:[auo]i|[auo])[^aeiouyäö]*)([aeiouyäö])\10$
```

Needless to say, I first suspected that I had made a mistake somewhere, so I dumbed the expression down little by little and finally got to this stage:

```
([aeiou])$|(.+)$
```

Which literally should mean "Match one vowel at the end of the string and use it as backreference 1 or if that fails, match just any character any number of times before end of the string and use it as backreference 2"

When used with a string like `foo` I'd expect the first part of the expression (`([aeiou])$`) to be used. Instead the second one is used and that confuses me.

If the quantifier is removed, the first option is used. I'm guessing that this has to do something with the greediness or specificity of the expression parts, though I thought that the expression is tested left to right.

Could someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: What happens if you use `([aeiou])$|.$`?

Comment: He said: *If the quantifier is removed, the first option is used.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Match one vowel at the end of the string [...] or **if that fails**, match just any character any number of times before end of the string [...]

No, that's not what it means. The correct interpretation is:

> Match **the longer of**:
>
> - one vowel at the end of the string
> - any character any number of times before end of the string
>
> (I don't know whether tie-breaking rules are well specified.)

Comment: Is it really always **the longer of**?

Comment: @Pichan: I wouldn't say "always" (different regex packages have different semantics). However, in this particular case *longest match*, *longest of the leftmost match* and *first valid match* all give the same result. And no regex package I ever came across has any sort of if-then-else logic for the `|` operator.

Comment: I was completely unaware of that. Thank you very much! Would you happen to know if there is an actual __OR operator__ or a way to micmic it in regex?

Comment: A small addition: This is a nice website that gives a lot of deep information on regular expressions : http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

It says that according to the Posix standard the longer has to be returned.

Comment: @KeesDijk: I've actually been reading that site and I'm using RegexBuddy to test my expressions. Partly the reason why I'm so surprised by this is because even RegexBuddy explains the pipe character with __(attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)__